# Finance - Random Portfolios using plyr and rportfolio - need to split columns

Tags: r, finance, plyr, reshape2

I am trying to compare an actual portfolio's performance to the performances of hypothetical random portfolios.

Here is a sample of the data set I am working with. It shows two months worth of data, the names of the managers in the portfolios, and the returns, allocations, and attributions of those managers.

```
"date" "manager" "return" "allocation" "attribution"
2005-01-31 "manager01" -0.00763241754291056 0.146 6.94549996404861e-05
2005-01-31 "manager02" 0.0292205518315147 0.048 4.09087725641205e-05
2005-01-31 "manager03" -0.0354047394153526 0.049 -8.85118485383814e-05
2005-01-31 "manager04" 0.0424244772606645 0.124 -0.000148485670412326
2005-01-31 "manager05" -0.0574606103881735 0.134 0.000206858197397425
2005-01-31 "manager06" 0.0465278163188542 0.098 -0.000265208553017469
2005-01-31 "manager07" 0.157063203979822 0.142 -0.000219888485571751
2005-01-31 "manager08" -0.0594342759491509 0.071 2.97171379745754e-05
2005-01-31 "manager09" -0.0199466865109495 0.093 6.18347281839434e-05
2005-01-31 "manager10" 0.118839410130508 0.095 0.000190143056208813
2005-02-28 "manager01" 0.0403671815817711 0.119 -0.000460185870032191
2005-02-28 "manager02" 0.0246109773791459 0.064 -3.93775638066334e-05
2005-02-28 "manager03" 0.00868489880733732 0.065 -4.08190243944854e-05
2005-02-28 "manager04" -0.082332291530606 0.105 2.46996874591818e-05
2005-02-28 "manager05" -0.0903959999837099 0.114 -0.000117514799978823
2005-02-28 "manager06" 0.0514735666329574 0.081 -6.17682799595489e-05
2005-02-28 "manager07" -0.00914374153663751 0.164 -8.41224221370651e-05
2005-02-28 "manager08" -0.0367283709786134 0.083 -4.77468822721974e-05
2005-02-28 "manager09" -0.04752320926613 0.079 -3.8018567412904e-05
2005-02-28 "manager10" -0.0657464361573664 0.126 -0.000309008249939622
```

In order to get the data into R, copy the data to the clipboard and then

```
mydata<-read.table("clipboard",header=TRUE)
```

In order to create the random portfolios I then use `ddply`, `mutate`, and `rlongonly` functions from `plyr` and `rportfolio`.

```
library(plyr)
library(rporfolio)

mydata.new<-ddply(mydata,.(date),mutate,new.attr=t(rlongonly(m=1,n=length(date),k=10,x.u=.15))*return)
```

In the `rlongonly` function:

- The value for m is the number of random portfolios I want to create.
- The value for n is the number of allocations for the time period.
- The value for k is the number of non zero allocations.
- The value for x.u is the upper limit for an allocation.

Attribution is merely return * allocation.

If I have m=1, everything is fine.
If I have m>1, the dimensions of the output are not correct.

```
mydata.new2<-ddply(mydata,.(date),mutate,new.attr=t(rlongonly(m=2,n=length(date),k=10,x.u=.15))*return)
dim(mydata.new)
```

mydata.new2 has only 6 columns when it should have 7.
The last column "new.attr" is basically 2 columns in one.

When I try to `melt` mydata.new2, I get the following error.

```
library(reshape2)
drop<-names(mydata.new2) %in% c("manager","return","allocation")
melt(mydata.new2[!drop],id="date")

> Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
> numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

How do I split up the "new.attr" column so that I can melt and graph the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I regenrate your data, you have to use dput(mydata) and post the result next time.

Then I generate your mydata.new2 vector.

```
library(plyr)
library(rportfolios)

mydata.new2<-ddply(mydata,
                  .(date),
                  mutate,
                  new.attr=t(rlongonly(m=2,n=length(date),k=10,x.u=.15))*return)
```

I round the numeric values , I and I show the data

```
 mydata.new2[,-c(1,2)] <- numcolwise(round_any)(mydata.new2,0.0001)
 head(mydata.new2)
        date   manager  return allocation attribution new.attr.1 new.attr.2
1 2005-01-31 manager01 -0.0076      0.146       1e-04    -0.0009    -0.0007
2 2005-01-31 manager02  0.0292      0.048       0e+00     0.0032     0.0040
3 2005-01-31 manager03 -0.0354      0.049      -1e-04    -0.0024    -0.0049
4 2005-01-31 manager04  0.0424      0.124      -1e-04     0.0029     0.0025
5 2005-01-31 manager05 -0.0575      0.134       2e-04    -0.0047    -0.0042
6 2005-01-31 manager06  0.0465      0.098      -3e-04     0.0051     0.0039
```

Here I have 7 columns and not 6 columns as you said.

I try to melt the data:

```
library(reshape2)
drop<-names(mydata.new2) %in% c("manager","return","allocation")
melt(mydata.new2[!drop],id="date")
```

But here you get the error:

```
 numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

beacuse of the **nested data.frame** new.attr in mydata.new2 data.frame. This is due to the use of **mutate**. Here it is better to use **transform** because you don't need to do transformation iteratively.

So :

```
mydata.new2<-ddply(mydata,
                  .(date),
                  transform,
                  new.attr=t(rlongonly(m=2,n=length(date),k=10,x.u=.15))*return)
```

and you get your result

```
head(melt(mydata.new2[!drop],id="date"))
        date    variable         value
1 2005-01-31 attribution  6.945500e-05
2 2005-01-31 attribution  4.090877e-05
3 2005-01-31 attribution -8.851185e-05
4 2005-01-31 attribution -1.484857e-04
5 2005-01-31 attribution  2.068582e-04
6 2005-01-31 attribution -2.652086e-04
```